# nextjs, typegoose, mongoose getting a typeerror right hand-side of instanceof not an object

Tags: typescript, mongoose, next.js, typegoose

I'm using mongoDB database and using typegoose and mongoose.  I have this file with the code below and I'm getting the error `TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object` on the last line where I call `getModelForClass(UserClass)`.  I've looked for hours and can't figure out how to get rid of this error. There is no circular reference as I've read it could be the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
import { ModelOptions, Severity, getModelForClass, index, post, prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

@post<UserClass>('save', function (doc) {
  if (doc) {
    doc.id = doc._id.toString();
    doc._id = doc.id;
  }
})
@post<UserClass[]>(/^find/, function (docs) {
  // @ts-ignore
  if (this.op === 'find') {
    docs.forEach((doc) => {
      doc.id = doc._id.toString();
      doc._id = doc.id;
    });
  }
})
@ModelOptions({
  schemaOptions: {
    timestamps: true,
    collection: 'users',
  },
  options: {
    allowMixed: Severity.ALLOW,
  },
})
@index({ username: 1 })
class UserClass {
  @prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  public username: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public firstName: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public lastName: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public hash: string;
  
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId | string;
  id: string;
}
export const User = getModelForClass(UserClass);
```

Comment: please provide what version of typegoose and typescript you are using, also the full error (with stacktrace)

Comment: I'm using typegoose version 11.5.0 and typescript version 5.2.2.  As for the error what I posted is all I'm getting.

Comment: i know that this is the complete error message, but i am asking for the error stack-trace, which should be available, otherwise i dont know where / what the problem is